# How to store chunks of Arrays in Json File to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, mongodb

I have 2.5GB of data in a csv file. I read the csv using createReadStream and writing in a json file.

```
const toObject = csvjson.stream.toObject();
    const stringify = csvjson.stream.stringify();

    createReadStream('../../excel_files/rtr/test.csv', 'utf-8')
        .pipe(toObject)
        .pipe(stringify)
        .pipe(createWriteStream('../../excel_files/result.json'))
        .on('error', function(err){
            console.log("error",err)
            reject(err);
        } )
        .on('finish', function(){
            flag = true;
            return resolve(flag); 
        } );

           var getStream = function () {
                var jsonData = '../../excel_files/result.json',
                    stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
                    parser = jsonStream.parse('*');
                return stream.pipe(parser);
            };
            getStream()
            .pipe(es.mapSync(async function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }))
```

Once done writing,I have read the json file using the above code. I have got multiple Json array of Objects (ie: Chunks of data).How to insert these Arrays into mongodb

[image: Json Output]

Comment: Are you unclear on the basics of inserting a document into MongoDB or is it a problem of iterating over your data set to insert those objects as new documents in your database?

Comment: The latter, how to iterate over the chunks of multiple Arrays and store into database. My json file:    [ {object},{object},{object},{object} ][ {object},{object},{object} ][ {object},{object},{object} ]

Comment: Did you miss putting another set of `[` and `]` around that? Because JSON strings cannot do a collection of arrays unless they are inside an object or another array. Details do matter.

Comment: While execute the above code, the resultant json file holds the multiple Arrays which contains n number of objects.

Comment: Yes, but are those arrays in an array? Top level, is there *one* array that contains those multiple arrays or an *object* that contains those arrays in an array in a property? *Show* a small example of the data or at least its structure instead of describing it. Without really seeing what the data looks like with concrete structure and property names, there is no way anyone could **guess** how to iterate over that data set.

Comment: Also, those details belong *in the question* to make the question complete and answerable. If the data is `"[{object},{object},{object},{object}][{object},{object},{object}][{object},{object},{object}]"` and assuming those `object` items are valid JSON for an object, the string itself *is not* JSON. There needs to be one *top level* object or array, there needs to be `,` between things in an array.

Comment: Hi,I have added the screenshot of the json output file.

Comment: No, that screenshot of data does not appear to be a file in JSON format, as I mentioned 2 days ago. See how your screenshot shows a red squiggle underline? Yep, that is indicating a formatting error. A file in JSON format would have an object or array at top level, and an array at top level would have commas between the array elements. You either need to fix your file to be "real" JSON or read it / parse it yourself to get the loose JSON elements that are within. You might want to read up here: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)